# How can I add music files in a runnable JAR file?

Tags: java

I am creating an runnable JAR file, and in my java project I have 3 music files. But when I creating runnable JAR file the music files doesn't comes with in it.

So has anyone any idea how to do?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The music files doesn't play when I have created the runnable JAR file. But the music plays when I run the program in Eclipse

Comment: Visit duplicate question (you may need to refresh this tab to see it on top of your post). It is about accessing image, but logic is same with any resource. Accepted answer has many links to other useful questions about solutions in different IDEs.